# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers' with unique index 'UserNameIndex'

Tags: sql, database, asp.net-identity

Cannot insert duplicate key row in object with unique index

I'm trying to transfer my users to a new database created by asp.net identity. But I get this error:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers' with
>   unique index 'UserNameIndex'.

My code is:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
(
[Id],
[UserName],
[UserNameRus],
[UserNameHeb],
[UserNameEng],
[Email],
[EmailConfirmed],
[PhoneNumberConfirmed],
[TwoFactorEnabled],
[LockoutEnabled],
[AccessFailedCount],
[Lang],
[isSendCommercial]
)
SELECT
NEWID(),
[UserName],
[UserNameRus],
[UserNameHeb],
[UserName],
[Email],
'false',
'false',
'false',
'true',
'0',
[Lang],
[isSendCommercial]
FROM [dbo].[Pj_Users]
```

Can some one explain to me, why do I get this error and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm the RDBMS? I assume it's MS SQL Server. Take a look at your unique index 'UserNameIndex' on the table 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. You will probably find it contains the column 'UserName' and that the table 'dbo.Pj_Users' has two rows with the same 'UserName'.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The code behind AspNetUsers is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    .
    .
    .
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([UserName] ASC);
```

In my old database, users had an unique email and could have nonunique username. I couldn't find an answer to resolve this issue, so I changed in database the last two lines to:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [EmailIndex]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([Email] ASC);
```

That solved my problem.